# Command line run error

Tags: c#, cmd

After looking on forums, I have written this snippet:

```
public string ExecuteCmd()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = this.m_command;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    return output;
}
```

The `m_command` is member of a class, initialized in the constructor. 
For my tests, it is `net user`. When the compiler arrives at this point, I get the following exception:

```
StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
//....
startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + this.m_command;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
//....
```

Comment: The code works, but the output is wrong, and always the same... http://imgur.com/0jNO6zp

Comment: You have a link in my comment with the output